# I am getting null value from input field on submit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend

I am trying to store data to database. But before that I want to make sure that I am getting data from fields. But I am getting [] in response. Here is the view code:

```
<form action="submit" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <h2><input type="file" name="imagefile"  /><br/>
                            <i class="fa fa-upload" style="font-size:20px;color:orangered"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Document</h2><br />
                                
                          <h4 style="font-size:15px;color:antiquewhite">Title</h4>
                                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="form-input"><br />
                                  
                        <br />
                        <h4 style="font-size:15px;color:antiquewhite">Category</h4>
                                    <select type="text" name="category" placeholder="Select">
                                        <option value="Arts and Craft">arts and craft</option>
                                        <option value="Business">business</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <br />
                                 
                                <button class="btnn" type="submit">Upload</button>
                     </form>
```

Here is controller code:

```
function uploadfilesuploader(Request $req)
    {
        $user = new uploader;
        $user-> title = $req->title;
        $user-> category = $req->category;        
        var_dump($user->title).die();
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@uploadfilesuploader');
```

I am expecting data from fields.
I have multiple post routes with submit. Could that be an issue?

```
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@savebuyer');
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@savefreelancer'); 
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@fsignin'); 
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@uploadfilesuploader');
```

As where ever I see they use this submit, so I used that. Could it confuse the web to which submit to use?

Comment: What is the content of `dd($req)`?

Comment: this is also showing null

Comment: Where is the `Request` in the method imported from?

Comment: use Illuminate\Http\Request;
I do have multiple submits, Maybe that could be issue?
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@savebuyer');
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@savefreelancer');
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@fsignin');
Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@uploadfilesuploader');

Comment: @RehmanAli Edit your post and add these there. I cannot read them and your question content would be completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured it out, the problem is in your multiple routes that has the same path. This is not gonna work unless the HTTP methods are different (one is `GET` and another one is `POST`). Change the others and use a related path to them. A friendly advice, watch a good course or read a good book for learning Laravel (there are plenty of them, and some good ones are free too.). If you do it now it would be easier than later.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow a good course. A quick question if you can clear my confusion. POST is used when we have to send data from the form. How can I differentiate this submit in Post Route "Route::post('submit','App\Http\Controllers\register@fsignin');"  so that I doesn't confuse since in form we use action="submit" . Is this submit a standard or I can use action ='someother word'

Comment: @RehmanAli We don't use POST to only send data. We can use GET to send data too. A short answer would be that POST is safer than GET. And `action` is not related to the name. `action` is the path to the route. You can replace the path that you wrote in the comment from 'submit' to 'signin' for example and others too.  For more info visit the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing).
And If my answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you @hosein for your precise and to the point answer. It helped.